# ffmpeg - compilation problem with g++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to run a program which uses ffmpeg libraries to decode a mp3 file. I am using following options for compiling the program:

```
g++ -c play.cpp -o play.o
g++ -o play play.o -L/usr/local/lib -lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice \
                   -lavfilter -ldl -lasound -L/usr/lib -lSDL -lpthread -lz -lswscale -lm
```

But while linking I am gettign following errors:

```
play.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `av_dup_packet(AVPacket*)'
play.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `av_malloc(unsigned int)'
play.cpp:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_audio3(AVCodecContext*, short*, int*, AVPacket*)'
play.cpp:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to `av_free_packet(AVPacket*)'
```

and so on...
These reported functions are available in the libavcodec.a etc. which i have already specified with the link options.
Can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here or suggest how to approach debugging this?

Comment: Sometimes the linking cannot deduce backwards references. Try to put `libavcodec.a` at the end of the compilation line.

Comment: And you can't compile ffmpeg with gcc instead?  Then link to it with g++?

Comment: Ah, Diego Sevillas comment is probably the thing to try

Answer (score 10):

Is this your own program, not the libav standard example? I might be wrong, but if so you probably could forget to specify extern "C" while including libav headers:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <avcodec.h>
#include <avformat.h>
}
```

This can be the problem 'coz you trying to compile sources with C++ compiler and libav (ffmpeg) is compiled using C compiler, so you must mark include headers for library as compiled by C compiler using extern C.

If you do mark includes as extern C already, please post some code chunk from your program to look at..

Comment: This is the answer that gets the job done! A bit weird that the libraries weren't "C++ aware" by default with the ifdef __cplusplus macro. This should be marked as the accepted answer so that it stands out better.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure with verbose linkin (`-Wl,--verbose`) that the right version of `-lavcodec` is chosen, and check with objdump or ldd if the symbols are truly in the library.

You might try switching the order of `-l` flags, these are very important; however, since play.cpp contains the references to functions in `-lavcodec`, the flag order already should be right.