# Unresolved externals trying to use ffmpeg

Tags: c++, linker, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use some functions from ffmpeg and am running into resilient linker errors. Here's what I did:

- Downloaded the latest 32-bit "Dev" build from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ (i.e. ffmpeg-20130418-git-ee94362-win32-dev)
- Created a "General - empty" C++ project in Visual Studio 2012 Premium
- Added the [ffmpeg]/lib folder to Linker -> Input -> "Additional Library Directories"
- Added "swscale.lib;avutil.lib;avformat.lib;avdevice.lib;avcodec.lib;" to Linker -> Input -> "Additional Dependencies"
- Added the following under C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories:

  - [ffmpeg]/include
  - [ffmpeg]/include/libswscale
  - [ffmpeg]/include/libavformat

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include "avformat.h"

int main()
{
    av_register_all();
}
```

This fails with:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   av_register_all(void)" (?av_register_all@@YAXXZ) referenced in
>   function _main

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/7514249/845568](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7514249/845568)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As you're using C++, you need to surround your ffmpeg `#include` statements with `extern "C"` like this :

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "avformat.h"
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I had actually tried that before and it didn't work, probably because of some other error in the project. Now it works... thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I assume this causes it to look for the undecorated "C" versions of the symbols instead of the decorated C++symbols?

Comment: @Deanna Yes, that's absolutely right. I'm glad you found the answer useful.

Comment: Perfect answer that worked.